# Add SunSed tag (a new programming language)

Tags: feature-request, tag-creation-process

I have just launched v3 of my startup: [sunsed.com](https://www.sunsed.com), the programmable CMS as a Service.

SunSed is also the name of the language (at first I gave it the name, HTML++, but decided to go with SunSed since it's easier to market one name).

SunSed strictly follows the HTML syntax (tags, attributes, etc). Here is a code example:

```
<s:set var="x">
    3
</s:set>
<s:put var="x">
```

Result:

```
3
```

You can create your own server-side tags like this:

```
<s:tag name="note">
    <s:style>
        .note{
             color: red;
        }
    </s:style>
    <div class="note">
        NOTE: {{@content}}!
    </div>
</s:tag>
<note> 
    Stack Overflow is Awesome 
</note>
```

Result:

```
<div class="note">
     NOTE: Stack Overflow is Awesome!
</div>
```

If you are interested in learning more, please checkout [the list of tags](https://www.sunsed.com/tags). It's still a work in progress and I haven't yet tried to market it. You are one of the first people to know about! You have no idea how excited I am! :)

It took me roughly 6 years to get to this point and all those years I have learned so much from SO, but unfortunately due to many personal shortcomings (which I'm currently working on) I have never contributed to SO. I just signed-up a few days ago and started contributing to be able to gather enough reputation to be able to ask this question here. It would be awesome if someone add the tag SunSed!

I'm planning to ask and answer most frequent questions that I have got from a few people who have tried the language. It would be awesome, to have all of our users ask technical questions about the language on SO which makes it easier for new users to find answers to previously asked questions.

We are going to use SO only for programming related questions and not for general support.

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how tags work. Tags do not exist first. Questions exist first. No one can create a tag if there is not yet a question that would use it. We generally prefer you have several good questions already on the site before someone will bother adding the appropriate tag for it.

Comment: Then what tag should I add to a question about a new language? Java? PHP? What?

Comment: Tags are used to categorize programming languages & frameworks (including CMS) which already in familiar use for multiple conditions. It not primarily used to promote any kind of commercial suite/tools, including self-created & published CMS as provided in link.

Comment: Side note: you are reinventing the [templating language in an XML namespace wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_Attribute_Language). You are using the Google App Engine, so presumably a [Python implementation](http://chameleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) would suit you. Or use the [PHP port](https://phptal.org/), or a [Java implementation](https://github.com/davidcana/ZPT-Java). Disclaimer: I helped develop Zope and Zope Page Templates, once upon a time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When someone has a question about your language, that'll be an appropriate time to create the tag.  Until then, I see no real reason to bother.

We don't create tags to promote things.  We create tags to help categorize topics in programming.

Comment: I don't disagree there @Sed, but there are [limits to self-promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/175248).  My advice:  let it happen organically.  Astroturfing this will *not* bode well for you.

Comment: @Sed:  Mm...no.  That's not how this works, unfortunately.  We have to have a compelling reason (and you need to have an on-topic question) to add it.